# How do I find the time elapsed, in ms, between one line of output to the next?

Tags: osx

I am running a command on my OS which outputs thousands of lines, sometimes delaying in the middle for a couple of seconds, before restarting. Is there a way to find the time elapsed, in ms, between these lines of outputs?

A time stamp would work but I would prefer to output the time differences to a file.

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) first and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

If you have homebrew, install `moreutils` to get the `ts` command, which can add incremental timestamps to input:

```
$ (echo foo; sleep 0.1; echo bar; sleep 0.2; echo foo) | ts -i '%.s'
0.000013 foo
0.077336 bar
0.210087 foo
```